# Chrome Extension to save Ctrl+F find in page history

Tags: chrome, history

Is there an extension that can save previously searched for keywords from the “find” box so that I can quickly retrieve the history?

By “find” I mean <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> (find in a page).